# Change Jobs for Wordpress templates

Tags: plugins, php, theme-development, templates

I'm using the [Jobs for Wordpress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/job-postings/#faq) plugin to post jobs on my clients website. I'm trying to change the templates so I can use my own style and layout, but I can't change the layout and position of the elements.

I copied the single-jobs.php file to my custom theme, but I only see one link that imports all the fields at one place.

```
<?php if( function_exists('get_job_fields') ) get_job_fields(); ?>
```

This code imports all the fields that are used, but I want to organise them in my way so I can work ik columns, add titles, etc. .Has anyone found a way how to insert the fields separately and position them where I want?

Comment: Please, make sure that you are using the proper template file.

Comment: Which files do I need?

Comment: You said you copied the file from the plugin. Are you sure the page is using the copied file, not the original file?

Comment: Yes, it's using the right file, but the fields are imported by 1 rule all at the same place. I added more details to my question above.